# Getting an error to install pyemd even though I just installed it

Tags: python, installation, word2vec, gensim

Here is the code:

```
from pyemd import emd

print("sentence 1:")
print(input_document_lower[0])
print("sentence 2:")
print(input_document_lower[1])
print("similarity:")
model_w2v.wmdistance(input_document_lower[0], input_document_lower[1])
```

Here's the error:

```
sentence 1:
incorrect batch number printed primary label pbn
sentence 2:
unconfirmed oos met vial washing qualification sample per 
similarity:

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-50af089a2354> in <module>()
      4 print(input_document_lower[1])
      5 print("similarity:")
----> 6 model_w2v.wmdistance(input_document_lower[0], input_document_lower[1])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.pyc in wmdistance(self, document1, document2)
   1308         Refer to the documentation for `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.wmdistance`
   1309         """
-> 1310         return self.wv.wmdistance(document1, document2)
   1311 
   1312     def most_similar_cosmul(self, positive=None, negative=None, topn=10):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.pyc in wmdistance(self, document1, document2)
    386 
    387         if not PYEMD_EXT:
--> 388             raise ImportError("Please install pyemd Python package to compute WMD.")
    389 
    390         # Remove out-of-vocabulary words.

ImportError: Please install pyemd Python package to compute WMD.
```

It is being installed properly so I really have no clue as to what is going wrong. Have any of your encountered this?

Comment: Just to be documented. Note, that pyemd at this time supports python 3.6 or lower. I tried to install it on 3.7 and got the error Command "/Users/myuser/Documents/projects/scoring/venv/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/p4/dcysb3fj7y12vc89m5jymp_40000gn/T/pip-install-luqazulu/pyemd/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/p4/dcysb3fj7y12vc89m5jymp_40000gn/T/pip-record-xde7ar9c/install-record.txt --single-version-ext

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, and for me the solution was to swap:

```
from gensim.similarities import WmdSimilarity
from pyemd import emd
```

into

```
from pyemd import emd
from gensim.similarities import WmdSimilarity
```

Don't ask me why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this as following -

If your `pip` install is not working use `conda` install instead by using this command

`conda install -c conda-forge pyemd`

I believe that now you have successfully installed pyemd. Now when it comes to thowing error even after importing successfully do as following - 
import `pyemd` before any `gensim module`. I mean pyemd should be on top.

```
from pyemd import emd
from gensim.similarities import WmdSimilarity
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedLineDocument
```

I hope you are done with this concern :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues, I installed this package in my virtual env, but it doesn't work. Then I rebooted my computer, and after that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line shown below

```
global PYEMD_EXT
```

just above the try:except code block

```
try:
    from pyemd import emd
    PYEMD_EXT = True
except ImportError:
    PYEMD_EXT = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the keyedvectors.py file and delete the try catch block.

This:

```
  try:
        from pyemd import emd
        PYEMD_EXT = True
    except ImportError:
        PYEMD_EXT = False
```

Remove the import error prompt

```
if not PYEMD_EXT:
            raise ImportError("Please install pyemd Python package to compute WMD.")
```

add this

```
from pyemd import emd
```

To know more about the bug check, https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2229/files

Even after this code throws an error. One possible problem is you'll running in jupyter, so restart the whole karnel it will do!!!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac and Linux, the `pip install pyemd` works fine.

However, on Windows, you may experience an issue in installing this.

This error occurs due to

> pyemd needing some C++ dependencies during build time.

This can be resolved by installing the `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019` as follows:

- Download "Build Tools for Visual Studio" https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019
- Run the .exe file and select to install C++ build tools
- Check that among the suggested packages to install it is also selected "Windows 10 SDK" (the newest version is fine) as this is the critical dependency
- Once the installation has finished reopen your PowerShell/Command Prompt and retry to install the library with the original pip instruction

Answer (score -1):

Check the documentation of wmdistance method

Warnings
    --------
    This method only works if `pyemd <https://pypi.org/project/pyemd/>`_ is installed.

```
If one of the documents have no words that exist in the vocab, `float('inf')` (i.e. infinity)
will be returned.

Raises
------
ImportError
    If `pyemd <https://pypi.org/project/pyemd/>`_  isn't installed.
```

so before using the wmdistance install package pyemd

pip install pyemd

Comment: The question includes: "even though I just installed it"